Gradle - remove shaded dependency of another dependency
I'm using the gradle dependency - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/3.4.0
And I was trying to exclude the org.eclipse.jetty-io dependency that shows up in the shaded folder. (I decompressed the jar to view the contents)
shaded -> 
   org -> 
      eclipse -> 
         jetty ->
            io

Sharing some images of the same:
This is the maven META - INF from the same lib:

This is the folder structure:

I tried adding the exclude in this manner:
implementation(group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.13', version: "${toolVersions.apacheSparkVersion}") {
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', module: 'jetty-io'
}

The exclusion seems to have no effect. What am I missing here and how can I avoid that dependency?
